# Am I missing something with my Thymeleaf th:onload?

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm iterating through a list of Message Objects.

I'm using `th:each` to create a table that I can add functionality to. My problem is that when I'm trying to pass a `messageId` over to a function that will be used to set a variables value, the `th:onload` isn't invoking it. I'm using the exact same syntax for a `th:onclick` that invokes a function and it works as expected.

Am I missing something?

```html
<td class="td-text" th:attr="onload=|passMessageId('${messageobj.messageId}')|">                   
</td>
```

Comment: The `onload` method usually relies on an event to happen then it is triggered and is not applicable in your use case. What are you trying to achieve with the `onload` method?

Comment: The goal is to have the value of 'messageId' invoked and passed into the function when the page is loaded.

Comment: what would the function do?

Comment: The function takes in the value of messageId and set a global variable with it. I'd then use that variable to get an element by Id (which shares the same messageId value). I'll use that element to set an element's attribute checkbox to 'checked' when a certain event occurs. I'm just trying to pass the messageId down the line sinces I have it in a List on the model thats being looped through. Outside of the loop I can't grab the Id. Which is why I'm trying to pass it along on page load.

Comment: I am just wondering, the message id for all the items in the list is the same? if so, you can extract it in your model and send it to thymeleaf. It will be easier this way. Then you can map that one field from your model directly to a javascript variable.

If message ids are not the same, then how are you determining which js variable to update when the function is invoked?

Comment: Sadly, they are all different. unique to each message. I have the variable set (var collectedId;) 
Would you know how I could get the th:onload to function properly?

Comment: I think **onLoad** is not applicable to **td** tag. You should check Technical Details section of the following link: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp

Comment: Okay. I'll read up on it. Thanks. I just found it strange because I could execute a different function but using onclick.. odd.

Comment: @Kruzik onClick is already defined on the element td but not onLoad. If you want to to something similar to onLoad of td you should do it in body onLoad and use a id selector or similar mechanism.